# Search Bar disappeared from view while typing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I added `SearchBar` to my `TableView` in `ViewDidLoad()` doing it:

```
    self.searchBar = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.searchBar.searchResultsUpdater = self

    self.searchBar.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchBar.searchBar.sizeToFit()

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar.searchBar
    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

everything works fine, but when I tap on this `SearchBar` it disappears. It means, I can still typing, and I can see the results but, don't see `SearchBar`. I implemented `UISearchBarDelegate` and I have been trying to add

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
```

but it still doesn't work. Do you have any idea, why this `Search Bar` disappears?

solution of this problem is (like @sandy sad) write this line of code in `viewDidLoad()`

```
 self.aNavigationController?.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

but now I have a new problem it's mean When I select row in `TableView` and display new `VievController`, `SearchBar` doesn't disappear and I see it in new view. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars to true in viewDidLoad().

```
self.aNavigationController?.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

Comment: It works! thx! but I have another problem. What I need to do when I click in Result list and move into new view and `searchbar` don't want to disappear? I try with it `func searchBarResultsListButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
    }` but doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to self.definesPresentationContext = true ?

Answer (score -1):

Actually the `search Bar` is not hiding it is just adjusting it `width` and `height` according to the text.

> Remove this line from your code and it will work fine.

```
self.searchBar.searchBar.sizeToFit()
```